# Perl: How do you convert this to a subroutine?

Tags: perl

The purpose of the subroutine is to check if the word pasttense is in both the other scalars passed in, and then perform a substitution and return that.

Original working code:

```
        if ($sentences[$i] =~ /\b$pasttense/i and $firstword[1] =~ /\b$pasttense/i) {
            $subsentences[$i] =~ s/$pasttense/ **$pasttense** /ig;
                        }
        elsif ($sentences[$i] =~ /\b$pastpart/i and $firstword[1] =~ /\b$pastpart/i) {
            $subsentences[$i] =~ s/$pastpart/ **$pastpart** /ig;
                        }
        elsif ($sentences[$i] =~ /\b$thirdsing/i and $firstword[1] =~ /\b$thirdsing/i) {
            $subsentences[$i] =~ s/$thirdsing/ **$thirdsing** /ig;
                        }
        elsif ($sentences[$i] =~ /\b$presentpart/i and $firstword[1] =~ /\b$presentpart/i) {
            $subsentences[$i] =~ s/$presentpart/ **$presentpart** /ig;
                        }
        elsif ($sentences[$i] =~ /\b$search_key$pluralsuffix/i and $firstword[1] =~ /$search_key$pluralsuffix\b/i) {
            $subsentences[$i] =~ s/$search_key$pluralsuffix/ **$search_key$pluralsuffix** /ig;
                        }
        elsif ($sentences[$i] =~ /\b$search_key/i and $firstword[1] =~ /\b$search_key\b/i) {
            $subsentences[$i] =~ s/\b$search_key/ **$search_key**/gi;
                        }
```

MY ATTEMPT:

```
sub suffix_changer_and_highlighter {

my ($presentword, $check1, $check2) = @_; ##search_key##parsewords[1] or firstword[1]##sentences
my $pluralsuffix = 's'; ##unless ends in y
require 'verbTenseChanger.pl';
my $pasttense = changeVerbForm($presentword,0,1); 
my $pastpart = changeVerbForm($presentword,0,2);
my $thirdsing = changeVerbForm($presentword,0,3);
my $presentpart = changeVerbForm($presentword,0,4);

    if ($check2 =~ /\b$pasttense/i and $check1 =~ /\b$pasttense/i) {
        return s/$pasttense/ **$pasttense** /ig;
    }
    elsif ($check2 =~ /\b$pastpart/i and $check1 =~ /\b$pastpart/i) {
        return s/$pastpart/ **$pastpart** /ig; 
    }
    elsif ($check2 =~ /\b$thirdsing/i and $check1 =~ /\b$thirdsing/i) {
        return s/$thirdsing/ **$thirdsing** /ig; 
    }
    elsif ($check2 =~ /\b$presentpart/i and $check1 =~ /\b$presentpart/i) {
        return s/$presentpart/ **$presentpart** /ig; 
    }
    elsif ($check2 =~ /\b$presentword$pluralsuffix/i and $check1 =~ /$presentword$pluralsuffix\b/i) {
        return s/$presentword$pluralsuffix/ **$presentword$pluralsuffix** /ig;
    }
    elsif ($check2 =~ /\b$presentword/i and $check1 =~ /\b$presentword\b/i) {
        return s/\b$presentword/ **$presentword**/gi;
    }
}
```

It's called by:

```
$subsentences[$i] =~ suffix_changer_and_highlighter($search_key, $firstword[1], $sentences[$i]);
```

I get an error saying the s/// is uninitialized. Sorry if this is elementary, however I am new to Perl. Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: if perl >=5.010 try `given`-`when` [see perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all your tests and substitutions follow the same pattern.  So I converted the if/elsif/ logic chain to data, and process an array of possible tests.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use My::VerbTenseChanger qw( changeVerbForm );

sub suffix_changer_and_highlighter {

    my ($presentword, $check1, $check2) = @_; ##search_key##parsewords[1] or firstword[1]
                                              ##sentences
    my $pluralsuffix = 's';                   ##unless ends in y

    my @verbforms = map changeVerbForm( $presentword, 0, $_ ), 1..4;

    for my $form ( @verbforms ) {
         if( $check1 =~ /\b$form/i and $check2 =~ /\b$form/i ) {
             $check2 =~ s/\b$form/ **$form**/ig;
             return $check2;
         }
    }

    return;
}
```

Also, don't use require to execute a perl library into your main script.  This has not been standard practice since Perl 4--that is, the early 90s.  Kick your tutorials in the ass.  They are out of date.

Instead make a module and export your functions so that they can be imported.

```
package My::VerbTenseChanger;  # Declare a new namespace.

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );  # Import the import function from exporter.

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( changeVerbForm );  # List the functions that can be exported.

sub changeVerbForm {

    # Here's your normal code you had before.
}   


1;   # Make sure you end the file with a TRUE value like 1.
```

`use` will expect the above package to be in the file `My/VerbTenseChanger.pm` relative to any place in your module search path (`@INC`).  The easiest place to keep stuff for a project is in the same directory as your main program.

```
MyGrammarianProject
 |- verby_magic <------------- This is your script.
 \- My <---------------------- This is a subdirectory
    \- VerbTenseChanger.pm  <- This is the module file
```

Whew, and finally, you might want to take a look at the various [Lingua modules on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/modlist/String_Language_Text_Processing/Lingua).

Comment: Great answer, really simplified the code! Thanks for the extra info as well. I will see if this works, thanks again.

Comment: The only issue was the map statement came up with an error saying it didn't expect a number. So I went with a for loop.

Comment: Not sure why `map` would complain about expecting numbers.  It just operates on a list to make a new list.  This sample one-liner doesn't have any problems:  `perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; print map foo($_), 1..4; sub foo { ">@_\n" }'`  What was the full error?

Comment: @Jon, often times you can massively reduce code by decomposing it into data.  This approach works in any language.  I've used it in C as well as Perl.  Perl makes this technique particularly powerful with its powerful primitive types, list based subroutines and argument flattening.

Comment: Alright, not sure what happened (I may have forgotten the comma before the numbers), but now map works like a charm. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Jon, it probably was the missing comma.  Confusingly enough, `map { BLOCK } LIST` has no comma, while `map EXPRESSION, LIST` does.  As you learn perl you'll find that `map`, `grep` and similar functions are a powerful way to work with data.  Also, check out slices, array and hash slices allow you to access multiple elements of these compound structures at once.  Very handy in combination with Perl's list-fu.

Comment: My attempt at a summary of slices: Used to access certain elements of another array or hash.
Map: Return the modified version of your array based on the EXPR
Grep: Return original value of array if it meets the criteria

Comment: @Jon, by Jove you've got it!  These things seem to cause many to stumble, but you've got it.  If you have a complex series of transforms to apply to a data, you can chain them. For example: `@foo = map uc, map s/\W+/ /, grep defined, @bar{ keys %buz };`  Takes the values of members of `%bar` that are in `%buz`, replaces non-word characters with spaces, and makes them upper case and puts the results in `@foo`.  Which is a pretty contrived example, but by chaining transforms you can simplify complex code and make it more understandable.  Keep up the good work.  BTW, check out perlmonks.org

Answer (score 2):

Your `s///` expression is not acting on anything.  You need to do:

```
$check2 =~ s/\b$search_key/ **$search_key**/gi;
return $check2;
```

Or whatever makes sense.  In the above code, the `$check2` variable will be changed according to the switch statement.  The returned value from a switch statement is the number of changes which I doubt is what you want to return.

Does that help?

Comment: Ya that helped a lot in getting me started. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your subroutine isn't returning anything (well... anything useful). You need to add a [return](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) and return some sort of value you can use in your `s///` command.

By the way, unless you want to use [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), you can't simply return the text string for whatever command you're doing here:

```
$subsentences[$i] =~ suffix_changer_and_highlighter($search_key,
                         $firstword[1],
                         $sentences[$i]);
```

I'm assuming from the `=~` you're trying to do some sort of substitution. Right? In this case, you need to pass `$subsentence[$i]` into your subroutine, and then do the replace there. Then you can simply return the value:

```
$subsentences[$i] = suffix_changer_and_highlighter($search_key,
                        $firstword[1],
                        $sentences[$i]);
```

Otherwise, you need to return a list of quoted regular expressions using the `qr` function, and maybe something like this:

```
 my ($from, $to) = suffix_changer_and_highlighter($search_key,
                        $firstword[1],
                        $sentences[$i]);
 $subsentences[$i] =~ s/$from/$to/;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for recognizing my problem!  Can you pass as many things as you want into a subroutine? Also, as shown above, would it have the same effect if $check2 was replaced and returned? Important: I can't change $sentences[$i] which... would the methods above change it?

Comment: The parameters in the subroutine are passed as a list in the `@_` list. In theory, it can be infinite. You can return a list or hash, so you can also return as many items as you want. The variables you declare in your subroutine are local to that subroutine (especially if you declare them with `my`). The problem is attempting to pass in more than one list or hash in your subroutine since everything is passed as one big list. To get around this, you can pass references to the list or hashes.